# Woocommerce custom billing field data not showing in the email after update

Tags: email, woocommerce, field

I have a problem where a custom field (let's call it billing_type) shows up correctly on the billing information page and used to work in the emails. The field data can be seen by opening the order in woocommerce dashboard but doesn't appear in the emails anymore.

After the update the email config seems to have changed. I've been trying to add a shortname (like adq_order_note for example) without success so I could use it in the email "Content" field in the dashboard aswell as adding it to the $fields array but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please share little piece of code what you tried first.

Comment: that's the problem, I can't find anything online about adding a shortname for the field's data. The old email config didn't have the kind of content editor it does now so I assume it automatically added the data into the email before. Now I have to format the email myself and I can only add data that can be done through preset shortnames.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'billing_type_checkout_field_order_meta_fields', 10, 3);

function billing_type_checkout_field_order_meta_fields($fields, $sent_to_admin, $order) {

    $fields['billing_type'] = array(
        'label' => __('Billing Type'),
        'value' => get_post_meta($order->id, 'billing_type', true),
    );

    return $fields;

}
```

Have you tried like this.?
Try adding this code snippet into your active theme's functions.php

Comment: I have tested similiar snippet I found but without luck. Updating woocommerce added more ways to edit emails. I tested this and no luck. All the other details print just fine. I also checked the theme folder for any incompabilities but didn't find anything that might be in the way.

Comment: I can also confirm that editing the "content" field on woocommerce email template changes the output.

Comment: Please check the field key is correct in the code snippet.

Comment: I noticed it when I tried the code. I believe it has something to do with woocommerce-quotation plugin. I'm trying to see if there's anything wrong with files of that plugin.

Comment: I did some digging and I believe the quote plugin is the reason for this behaviour (https://woocommercequoteplugin.com). I'll try to contact them.